# Show that $P(A \cap B)\in[0.4, 0.6]$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $P$ be a probability distribution on a sample space $\Omega$ and let $A, B \subseteq\Omega$ be events with $P(A) = 0.6$ and $P(B) = 0.8$. Suppose that the value $P(A \cap B)$ is unknown. Show that $P(A \cap B) \in [0.4, 0.6]$.

I really don't know where to start any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to draw a Venn diagram and use inclusion-exclusion principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the cardinal number of the union of two sets is greater than or equal to the cardinal number of the set containing more elements, i.e.,  $P(A \cup B) \in [0.8,1]$

We also know that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$

$\implies - P(A \cap B) + 0.6 + 0.8 = P(A \cup B) $

$\implies P(A \cap B) - 0.6 - 0.8 \in [-1, -0.8]$

$\implies P(A \cap B) \in [0.4,0.6]$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$P(A)+P(B)=0.6+0.8=1.4$$

thus as this probability cannot be greater than 1 the minimum value of $P(A\cap B)=0.4$

On the other hand, $P(A\cap B)$ cannot be greater than the minimum probability of the two events...this happens when $A \subset B$ that is $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$

concluding:

$$P(A\cap B) \in[0.4;0.6]$$

These are the two extreme situations

[image]